# Parse Json object using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the response I am getting from one of my authentication API.

```
{"auth":"413e193fe7d10011230b:cea7abe015a6c8d2a78c8dbb48a21f769f65e79441809e918d6e7e98913aeca3","channel_data":"{\"user_id\":\"969696\",\"user_info\":{\"name\":\"Sandra Smith\"}}"}
```

I would like to get values user_id and user_info from the above response using jquery or javascript. How can I do that?

Comment: use JSON.parse(obj)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.parseJSON` or `JSON.parse`

```js
var json={"auth":"413e193fe7d10011230b:cea7abe015a6c8d2a78c8dbb48a21f769f65e79441809e918d6e7e98913aeca3","channel_data":"{\"user_id\":\"969696\",\"user_info\":{\"name\":\"Sandra Smith\"}}"};

//using javascript
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));

var channel_dataObj= JSON.parse(obj.channel_data);
var user_id =channel_dataObj.user_id;

console.log(user_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why jquery for this. Just use JSON.parse(some)

Comment: This will not work as there is a nested JSON string you currently do not parse.

Comment: I am getting error as SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: You can check updated answer

Comment: Getting error as TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined

Comment: you can simply do JSON.parse(obj.channel_data), then assign it to variable, there you can take user_id and user_info

Comment: You can check I have added code snippet

Comment: @BharatsingParmar, I used your code, I am getting error as TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of null.
My Code is as follows:
`
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(member));
 var channel_dataObj = JSON.parse(obj.channel_data);
 var user_id = channel_dataObj.user_id;`

Comment: have you checked and run code snippet? Its working fine. Please check answer and implement it accordingly

Comment: @BharatsingParmar, Yes your code is perfect but when I try to access the user_id in my function, I am getting error as **SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0**

`function addUser(member) {
   var json = member; //Response from api

 //Using jQuery
 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(json));
 //OR 
 //using javascript
 var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
 
 var channel_dataObj= JSON.parse(obj.channel_data);
 var user_id =channel_dataObj.user_id;
 alert('Online'+user_id);`
}